# React.js getTimeUntil returns Nan

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a tutorial trying to learn React.js.  This is a countdown app.  When I try to run it the time comes back as Nan (Not a number).  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Clock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     days: 0,
     hours: 0,
     minutes: 0,
     seconds: 0
   };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getTimeUntil(this.props.deadline);
  }

  getTimeUntil(deadline) {
    const time = Date.parse(deadline) - Date.parse(new Date());
    console.log("time", time);
    const seconds = Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((time / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((time / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    const days = Math.floor(time / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    this.setState({ days, hours, minutes, seconds });
  }

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
        <div className="Clock-days">{this.state.days} Days</div>
        <div className="Clock-hours">{this.state.hours} Hours</div>
        <div className="Clock-minutes">{this.state.minutes} Mins</div>
        <div className="Clock-seconds">{this.state.seconds} Secs</div>
     </div>
    );
   }
  }

 export default Clock;
```

I define the deadline in the App.jsx file Please check out the file below as to the code.:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Clock from "./Clock";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     deadline: "December 25, 2017",
     newDeadline: ""
   };
 }

  changeDeadline() {
   this.setState({ deadline: this.state.newDeadline });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-title">Countdown to {this.state.deadline}
          </div>
           <div>
            <Clock dealine={this.state.deadline} />
           </div>
         <div>
          <input
           placeholder="new date"
            onChange={event =>
             this.setState({ newDeadline: event.target.value })}
         />
         <button onClick={() => this.changeDeadline()}>Submit</button>
       </div>
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

thank you for your assistance in helping a React Newbie.

Comment: How does your `deadline` prop look like? Try console logging the `deadline` and `new Date()` and post it here.

Comment: class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      deadline: "December 25, 2017",
      newDeadline: ""
    };
  }

Comment: Please edit the post with parent component that has `deadline` defined. It's difficult to understand from the comment.

Comment: deadline undefined

Answer (score 1):

I forgot the second "d" in deadline on the app.jsx file.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Haha. That's unexpected!

Comment: LMAO None of us ever typo :-)